# Something wrong in the body of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that have to return True if and only if all the ints in L1 are the lengths of the strings in L2 at the corresponding positions. and the Precondition: len(L1) == len(L2).

*EXAMPLE:*

```
>>> are_lengths_of_strs([4, 0, 2], ['abcd', '', 'ef']) 
True
```

Below is the function:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    result = True
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        if i in len(L1) != len(L2):
            result = False
    return result
```

It result in a error. The line  `if i in len(L1) != len(L2):` is the wrong . Can someone help me in this line ??

Obs : I have to use `!=`

Comment: "Something rotten in the state of Danmark"

Comment: +1 to sehe's comment, __please__ use descriptive titles for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected version of your code:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    result = True
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        if L1[i] != len(L2[i]):
            result = False
    return result
```

Note that this is not pythonic, because you don't in fact need an index here:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    result = True
    for i, l in zip(L1, L2)
        if i != len(l):
            result = False
    return result
```

Even shorter:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    return all(i == len(l)
        for i, l in zip(L1, L2))
```

Answer (score 0):

use the built-in `all()` along with `zip()`:

```
In [5]: all(x==len(y) for x,y in zip([4, 0, 2], ['abcd', '', 'ef']))
Out[5]: True
```

or if `!=` is compulsory use `any()`:

```
In [7]: not any(x != len(y) for x,y in zip([4, 0, 2], ['abcd', '', 'ef']))
Out[7]: True
```

or improving your code:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    for x,y in zip(L1,L2):
        if x!=len(y):
            return False
    return True


In [12]: are_lengths_of_strs([4, 0, 2], ['abcd', '', 'ef'])
Out[12]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is probably the problem:

```
    if i in len(L1) != len(L2):
```

This checks if `i in len(L1)`, but `len(L1)` is an integer, which can't "contain" another number.

You have to iterate over the elements of each list:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    result = True

    for i in range(len(L1)):
        if L1[i] != len(L2[i]):
            result = False

    return result
```

Also, get rid of `result`. A simple `return` statement will work just fine:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        if L1[i] != len(L2[i]):
            return False

    return True
```

If you want to get even more Pythonic, use `zip`:

```
def are_lengths_of_strs(L1, L2):
    for a, b in zip(L1, L2)
        if a != len(b):
            return False

    return True
```